# Configure dnsmasq to translate local names for iPhones

Tags: dnsmasq, iphone, host-name-resolution

I've found that iPhone 5S won't resolve name of the host of the local network by it's name. It is only possible when adding `.local` suffix to the hostname, e.g. instead of asking (like on a Linux host):

```
https://local_hostname
```

one must use:

```
https://local_hostname.local
```

Is it possible to handle that by `dnsmasq` to use `https://local_hostname` on iPhone?

`dnsmasq` version is `2.76`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Unix StackExchange. Please always include your version numbers, so readers can date this answer... when Apple next decide to change everything :-P.  That is, please include the version(s) of iOS which you notice do not work, and also the version of dnsmasq which doesn't work with it :-).

Comment: It also occurs to me that you don't say whether you are _currently_ using a dnsmasq which you can configure, or if you need to know about the practicalities of setting up a dnsmasq where you can control the exact configuration because you're using a home router with dnsmasq or similar but the router does not allow you to edit the configuration file in the way you might need to.  So please, tell us which of these two options is true.

Comment: Your title is kind of bugging me as well, sorry :-). My answer _might_ work, but I would not describe it as translating domains. Perhaps you can rephrase the title to better summarize what you want to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.  It all depends whether iOS supports the DHCP option `domain-name`.

Configure dnsmasq to use a domain name.  I'm thinking of something like this link: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dnsmasq#Adding_a_custom_domain

Except, please use the domain `.test` to start with.  I would not trust whatever random domain the Arch wiki thinks is free to use this day of the week.  [If you violate standards, they can bite you with problems that are horribly difficult to debug](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/11/29/google_dev_network/).  You should be able to use `.test` fine for testing.  You might decide to use something different for the long term.  I included some other suggestions below.

Explanation:

### i asked how not to type a domain at the end, how could that possibly work if i configure dnsmasq to start using a domain?

There's an option in DHCP messages, `domain-search`, which defaults to the single domain set in `domain-name`. The client's DNS resolver is supposed to try appending each "search domain" in turn, if it can't find the name normally.  So the idea is that dnsmasq will be configured so that all the local names are placed in this domain.

If you want to use it like this, you probably don't have a preference as to what the domain looks like.  You just need to make sure it doesn't clash with any *real* domain, present or future :-).

Apparently `.test` is available because it is reserved, for developers who might want to set up systems like this.  This might not be *ideal*... by a similar argument, people might use it for testing inside their own laptop, and then be unable to access the local domain names when they connect to your network.

If you don't like the `.test` domain for whatever reason, you can register your own.  Free sub-domains (but registered with the Public Suffix List used for some web browser security), are currently available from [DuckDns.org](https://www.duckdns.org/).  Or reduce the collision probability, by using a sub-domain of `.test` selected randomly from a sufficiently large word list:

- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Special:Random
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random

### ok but then what's the point, if i don't want to type a domain then why would i add one?

> This functions seems to be broken by a recent iOS upgrade
>
> I still can browse by ip address. Is the ability to browse by local network names broken by the recent iOS upgrade or is there something wrong in my setup?

-- [Dec 14 2013](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/113814/70448)

My interpretation is that Apple have reserved "single-label" names; that they will not ask a DNS server for the address of a single-label name.  Hence the need to use a domain name and a search domain. Another example of software which does this:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.html

> Single-label names are routed to all local interfaces capable of IP multicasting, using the LLMNR protocol. Lookups for IPv4 addresses are only sent via LLMNR on IPv4, and lookups for IPv6 addresses are only sent via LLMNR on IPv6. Lookups for the locally configured host name and the "gateway" host name are never routed to LLMNR.

This is in compliance with the *informational* [RFC 4795](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4795), "Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution (LLMNR)".

> 3. Usage Model

> By default, an LLMNR sender SHOULD send LLMNR queries only for
> single-label names.  Stub resolvers supporting both DNS and LLMNR
> SHOULD avoid sending DNS queries for single-label names, in order to
> reduce unnecessary DNS queries.

Comment: The `.local` domain is special in the sense that, when an application asks for the system to resolve a name ending in `.local`, then (and only then) mDNS is used. In this case there is no alternative mechanism to mDNS for local names, so a lookup without the `.local` suffix won't work. What the OP really wants is for dnsmasq to act as a mDNS client and to configure dnsmasq to use mDNS for single-label names. I don't know if that's possible. Also, it's not fruitful to bring up LLMNR here. LLMNR is Microsoft's competing mechanism to mDNS, which Apple's Bonjour uses.

Comment: @JohanMyréen you're not listening. How do you think the _Linux hosts_ are able to resolve `https://local_hostname` ?

Comment: Maybe the Linux hosts use LLMNR, which is used for single-label names without a suffix or, for compatibility with mDNS, also allows a `.local` suffix. mDNS and LLMNR can coexist. The iPhone apparently only supports mDNS. Anyway, my point is that, in this case, obviously the only mechanism for serving local names is peer-to-peer multicast, be it mDNS or LLMNR. I.e. there is no central server; the hosts themselves respond with their names. If there is something in your answer I didn't get, please explain.

Comment: @JohanMyréen dnsmasq. My answer gives some details on configuring dnsmasq to use a domain. If you don't, it just does the same thing for single-label names. The hosts provide their hostnames to dnsmasq in the DHCP exchange.

Comment: So far, distributions tend not to enable systemd-resolved, so LLMNR support is less common than this dnsmasq approach.

Comment: @JohanMyréen you're right. In `dnsmasq.d` directory I have a file `test` which has content: `address=/test.company.local/192.168.2.10` (I've changed the original names). When I've added the second line: `address=/test.company/192.168.2.10` (without `.local` suffix), everything works well on iPhone. As @sourcejedi mentioned, as long as `test.company` doesn't clash with any _real_ domain name it should work fine.